# Check if the determinant of a positive definite matrix equals the product of its diagonal elements, then the matrix is diagonal

Tags: determinant, positive-definite

Let $A=[a_{ij}]\in M_n, $ and $A$ is a positive definite matrix, Show that $A$ is diagonal if $det(A)= \prod_{i=1}^n a_{ii}$.

I know a positive definite matrix is also  Hermitian, so it remains to show nondiagonal entries equals 0. But I don't know how to use the determinant condition to prove this statement. Please give some suggestions?
Thank you!

Comment: This is Hadamard’s determinant inequality.  Do you know what Cholesky Factorization is?  Equivalently does you know how to take a square root of a PD matrix and run QR factorization?  Alternatively this can be proven via majorization.

Comment: Thank you！I know how to take a square root of a positive definite matrix and Schur decomposition. But I have not yet learned about factorization.